# Update select list to match hashtag change on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a product page for a store with the ability to preview multiple images. As of right now the current image being viewed updates the # hashtag on the URL. I have a select list with each option that is tagged with a class matching each potential hashtag.

I got a start, but just not quite sure how to use jQuery to take the hashtag, match it with a class and do something. Would it be better to trigger a click or simply update the option to 'selected'?

Here is my start, not quite sure why it's not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/ykmgzyc7/

```html
var url = window.location.href;
var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf('#'));                          
$('option.' + hash).trigger('click');
```

Comment: Please post the HTML/JS which you have tried so far or any JSFiddle?

Comment: use url.substring(url.indexOf('#')+1); to get just the string without the #

Comment: I just added a JS fiddle. Hoping to get it working where you click the link with a hashtag and it updates the option to reflect that. https://jsfiddle.net/ykmgzyc7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't actually loading a new page and just using the anchors you can dynamically modify the selection with jquery.

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
</ul>

<select id="selectOptions">
<option class="one">One</option>
<option class="two">Two</option>
<option class="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
$("a").on("click",function(){
var link=$(this).attr('href');
var hash = link.substring(link.indexOf('#')+1);
$('#selectOptions option').removeAttr('selected');
$('#selectOptions .'+hash).attr('selected',true);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ykmgzyc7/3/

Comment: This is so close. I noticed after clicking through the list it would stop responding. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hash using:

```
(window.location.hash).split("").slice(1).join("")
```

This gets the hash, converts in a array of chars, removes the fisrt char (#) and converts again to a String.
Then you need a event handler for the Hash change event, where you assign the new value:

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
    var value = (window.location.hash).split("").slice(1).join(""); 
    $('#your_select_id').val( value );
};
```

Your HTML needs to be addapted to something like this, setting the value for each SELECT item:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
</ul>

<select id="your_select_id">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a JSFiddle going now. https://jsfiddle.net/ykmgzyc7/ Clicking any of the links should update the select list appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = window.location.href;
console.log(url);
var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf('#') + 1)
console.log(hash);
$('option.' + hash).trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
</ul>

<select>
<option class="one">One</option>
<option class="two">Two</option>
<option class="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I added it to my JSFiddle and it doesn't seem to be working. https://jsfiddle.net/ykmgzyc7/2/